# Finding position vector of orthocentre

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

I wanted to know the position vector of orthocentre of a $\triangle ABC$. Given position vectors of vertices as $A(\mathbf a),\,B(\mathbf b),\,C(\mathbf c)$, can we find a general formula for orthocentre like for centroid it is $\displaystyle G\left(\frac{\mathbf{a+b+c}}{3}\right)$. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's an example: https://tutors.com/math-tutors/geometry-help/how-to-find-orthocenter-of-a-triangle

Comment: -@Ginger Bread, what did you tried?

Comment: @SarGe I know the formula in terms of side lengths and angles ,just asked out of curiosity

Comment: In barycentric coordinates, we have $H:(\tan A:\tan B:\tan C)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signum function: $sgn(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$. $a,b,c,H$ are all vectors. $A,B,C$ are angles of the triangle.

$$cos(A)=(b-a)·(c-a)⇒tan(A)=sgn((b-a)·(c-a))\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{(b-a)·(c-a)}\right)^2-1}$$

$$cos(B)=(c-b)·(a-b)⇒tan(B)=sgn((c-b)·(a-b))\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{(c-b)·(a-b)}\right)^2-1}$$

$$cos(C)=(a-c)·(b-c)⇒tan(C)=sgn((a-c)·(b-c))\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{(a-c)·(b-c)}\right)^2-1}$$

$$H=\frac{atan(A)+btan(B)+ctan(C)}{tan(A)+tan(B)+tan(C)}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $O$ is a circumcenter for $ABC$ then we have $$\vec{OH} = \vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}$$

Now if is $O$ an origin of position vectors then $$\vec{H} = \vec{A}+\vec{B}+\vec{C}$$

or $H$(**a**+**b**+**c**)

---

How to prove that? Let $X$ be such a point in the plane of triangle that

$$\vec{OX} = \vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}$$ and try to find out, what can you say about $X$.

Hint: Observe vector $$\vec{OX} -\vec{OA}=\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Hint:** $$\vec{CH}=\vec{CB}+\lambda\vec{BL}\quad...(1)\\ \vec{CH}=\vec{CA}+\mu\vec{AK}\quad...(2)$$ Now, find conditions to eliminate $\lambda$ and $\mu$.